# Anonymity of session hijackers using dsploit

Tags: man-in-the-middle, forensics, browser-hijacking

I was wondering about the possibility of finding out culprits who hijacked others' sessions and tried using google to find an answer several times, but I always failed.

Before I ask a question, let's make some assumptions: assume that I am logged into several websites like amazon, facebook, google, or whatever it could be, and at some point a bad guy uses tools like dsploit, etc. to hijack my session and successfully achieves what he wants like manipulating my personal info, sending threat messages to my aquaintances, or other illegal stuff. Also assume that I found this out less than several hours after the attack and contacted authorities to bring the culprit to justice. Assuming that the authorities found it illegal and starts investigating the case, is it possible for authorities to trace back things to find out who the culprit is, where he lives, etc.?

P.S. I am asking this because I have a guy who speaks about hacking & dsploit stuff and recently there were victims who seem to have been attacked by hijacking or MITM. I think the guy is the culprit, but can't say for sure unless there is a clear evidence.

Comment: It all depends on the evidence that was gathered. You don't specify what the data is that points to an attacker.

Answer (score -1):

You have to look at the packets and monitor the activity on the network. With wireshark or tcpdump, netcat, tcpflow. You can play around with a lot of tools.